# Getting the filename if bean name is known in grails

Tags: java, grails, groovy

Can I find the filename if I know the bean name it contains?
For example: In resourcesFirst.groovy file:

```
beans{
    property(Property){bean->
        owner = "company"
    }
}
```

I know the bean name 'property', I need to find the filename 'resourcesFirst.groovy' from it.
Is there anything simple as:

```
Holders.applicationCOntext.getBean('property').getFilename()
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the question as asked is "no".